# Does Angular JS have an equivalent of dojo.hitch()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dojo

Forgive my ignorance as I am not as familiar with Angular js. Is there an equivalent to dojo.hitch()? It returns a function that is guaranteed to be executed in the given scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use the native JavaScript [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
var boundFunction = lang.hitch(this, myFunction);
```

is the same as

```
var boundFunction = myFunction.bind(this);
```